# Javascript does not redirect correctly

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form to upload an image and if it is successful, it should redirect to the same page and should be display the image. I used the below php and javascript code, and although uploading is successful it shows empty page. If I refresh the upload page manually, the image will load.

I used the below code to pass data to upload page. Unable to find any issue.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Successfully Uploaded Image");';
    echo "window.location.href ='../htdocs/reg-image.php?nic=$nic' ";
    echo 'window.location = "../htdocs/reg-image.php";';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Comment: try echo "location.reload();" ..

Comment: try `echo "window.location.href ='reg-image.php?nic=$nic' ";` the `htdocs` is your DocumentRoot and should not go on the `href`

Comment: Or better still `header('Location reg-image.php?nic=".$nic);`

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for this. If form action is different from the origin then use header.

Comment: I think `../htdocs` is from a localhost which means that when deploying the website it won't work.

Comment: nothing works for me

Comment: PHP is a server-side language and the browser cannot even see it; what counts is the **generated JavaScript code**. Plus you cannot redirect twice—the browser won't open new tabs automagically or anything similar.

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript for the redirect? You could just redirect using PHP. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php